# why does MaxAbsScaler() not set the column range to [-1,1]?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

From scikit learn documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html), I understand that MaxAbsScaler works by dividing each column by its maximum value. This should set the maximum to be exactly one, i.e equivalent to the transformation df=df/df.max().

This gives me the result I expect:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
max_abs_scaler = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,50), columns=np.arange(50))
dfdividebymax = df/df.max()
dfdividebymax.max(axis=0)
```

is an array of 1s, since every column maximum occurs at least once.
 However,

```
dftransformed = max_abs_scaler.fit_transform(df)
dftransformed.max(axis=0)
array([ 0.9542721 ,  0.95156696,  0.98142822,  0.86959599,  0.82640483,
        1.        ,  0.71766434,  0.97071355,  1.        ,  1.        ,
        1.        ,  1.        ,  0.96306546,  1.        ,  1.        ,
        0.96927375,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.90660616,
        1.        ,  0.93072587,  0.90154812,  0.81959713,  0.83557895,
        1.        ,  1.        ,  0.988002  ,  0.89144342,  0.74270055,
        0.66322889,  0.93516648,  0.84134716,  1.        ,  1.        ,
        1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.63151867,
        0.86357431,  0.71128973,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,
        0.69890436,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.95098563,  0.73306342])
```

outputs now several columns whose maximum is strictly less than 1. What is the reason that some maxima are missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing part lies in the fact that the transformer finds the maximum of the absolute values of your dataframe. As a result, if the absolute value is a negative in your original dataframe, you notice the "inconsistency" you pointed. In other words, in your random dataframe, the maximum absolute values of your first 5 features for instance, have negative values in df. You can see the transformation in line 784 of [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L696)

Comment: What is its transformation? Division by the maximum should not require an estimate of the mean, so I don't understand what benchmark it uses other than the column max.

Comment: As a matter of fact it is a division with the max_abs = np.abs(X).max(axis=0). As a result, it first finds the absolute value, and then the max. I will modified the answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you. So it first takes the absolute value of the df, and then does a max transform with this value. dfnew = df/(np.abs(df).max(axis=0))